# Converting large sql queries into json

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, json, jdbc

This question concerns the design of the best way to convert the result of a SQL query into JSON. Right now, I'm looping through the results of one query (users) and doing separate queries for the education and employment of each user to attach as a variable length JSON array (option 2 below). I'm  not sure if the way I'm doing it is the appropriate solution or if parsing a join table would be preferred. Here's my problem:

OPTION 1: I could use joins and get something like:

```
user  |  employment  | position       | education   | degree  
john  |  BCG         | consultant     | harvard     | MBA  
john  |  BCG         | consultant     | ut Austin   | bs  
john  | White house  | speechwriter   | harvard     | MBA  
john  | White house  | speechwriter   | ut Austin   | bs  
john  | Papa Johns   | delivery boy   | harvard     | MBA  
john  | Papa Johns   | delivery boy   | ut Austin   | bs  
rob   | google       | engineer       | ut Austin   | bs  
rob   | dropbox      | engineer       | ut Austin   | bs
```

OPTION 2:  I could alternatively do a query for the users which would give something like:

```
user  
john  
rob
```

and then could loop through those users in Java  and then do a query for each, i.e. for john I'd get:

```
employment     | postion  
BCG            | consultant  
whitehouse     | speechwriter  
papa johns     | delivery boy  
.... and a similar one for education.
```

This second option seems to make it easier to convert it into json, but I'd also have to make multiple SQL queries for each user, opening a connection each time. For the 1st option, I'm not quite sure how I'd convert that into json, but it should be doable.

If anybody can let me know which would be best practice, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Please show some effort. What code have you tried?

Comment: just use some ORM or another to do the grunt work for you.

Comment: Jorge, this is more of a design question, so I didn't think the code would be necessary. I've implemented the second option and it works, but I'm just not sure if it's less efficient than doing a join on education and employment and then parsing that to create a JSON representation of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Would the use of Node.js be an option?

You could query Mysql by a Node script. The query's result would be an JavaScript Object, which than you could easily transform in a JSON file and save to the disk.

**Required**

- NodeJs
- `npm install mysql`

**Node Script (untested!)**

```
var mysql = require('mysql'), //mysql connector
    fs = require('fs'), //file system
    data = [];

//connect to MySQL 
var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'your-username',
      password : 'your-password',
      database : 'db-name',
    }
);

connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM myTable';

//query MySQL 
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    //save result to local variable
    data = rows;
});

connection.end();

var outputFilename = '/tmp/my.json',
    jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2); //extra params for pretty printing

//save json to file
fs.writeFile(outputFilename, jsonString, function(err)         {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("JSON saved to " + outputFilename);
    }
});
```

If you query is too large, you could modify the code to Append lines to file (instead of writeFile) and also query for a query total first, then read chunks of rows and repeat till the total od rows in the query

Comment: Hi Thiago, unfortunately not. I might be able to switch to Node down the line, but for now the backend is written in Java.